# procmailrc - change email subject

Tags: procmail

I want to change subject for all subscription list emails by adding [BULK] to its.
Looks like global /etc/procmailrc file is the best place to do it.
But this filter also drops all headers for some emails (my changes separated by dashes):

```
LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail.log
TRAP=/etc/webmin/virtual-server/procmail-logger.pl
:0wi
VIRTUALMIN=|/etc/webmin/virtual-server/lookup-domain.pl --exitcode 73 $LOGNAME
EXITCODE=$?
:0
* ?/bin/test "$EXITCODE" = "73"
/dev/null
EXITCODE=0
:0
* ?/bin/test "$VIRTUALMIN" != ""
{
INCLUDERC=/etc/webmin/virtual-server/procmail/$VIRTUALMIN
}
-----
:0
* ^List-Unsubscribe:.*
{
   :0 hw
   SUBJECT=| formail -xSubject:

   :0 hfw
   * ^List-Unsubscribe:.*
   | /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [BULKMAIL] $SUBJECT"
}
-----
DEFAULT=$HOME/Maildir/
ORGMAIL=$HOME/Maildir/
DROPPRIVS=yes
```

Individual .procmailrc in user home dir rules with this code works perfect but its hard to manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce your problem, and you are not posting any diagnostics, but I can suggest a different recipe which might avoid a couple of possible error conditions.

There is no reason to repeat the `List-Unsubscribe:` conditions inside the braces -- if you are inside the braces, you know it matched.

The convention to hard-code the path to `formail` seems clunky (and you fail to do that in one of the places where you call it) but if Procmail gets invoked with a really wonky `PATH` that could be a reason you see failure when you don't specify fully the path `/usr/bin/formail`.

Anyway, you want to avoid external processes as far as possible.  Procmail can extract the Subject: header into `MATCH` and then you just need a single `formail` invocation for the entire recipe to succeed.

```
:0 hfw
* ^List-Unsubscribe:
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [BULKMAIL]$MATCH"
```

The special operator `\/` causes Procmail to collect the matching string into the variable `MATCH`, and we then use that instead of the external `formail -xSubject:` you were running.  This is hardly a crucial change, but should be more efficient, as well as easier to read and debug.

(The trailing wildcard `.*` is superfluous in the first regex; Procmail is satisfied if a match is found anywhere in a line.)

You can test from the command line (but this of course requires that your recipe file doesn't override `DEFAULT`):

```
root@vbvntv-docker:/# procmail DEFAULT=/dev/null VERBOSE=yes </tmp/nst.eml
procmail: [937] Thu Dec  1 06:57:20 2016
procmail: Rcfile: "/etc/procmailrc"
procmail: Assigning "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
procmail: Match on "^List-Unsubscribe:"
procmail: Assigning "MATCH="
procmail: Matched " testing"
procmail: Match on "^Subject:\/.+"
procmail: Executing " /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [BULKMAIL]$MATCH""
procmail: Assigning "PATH=/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/dev/null"
procmail: Opening "/dev/null"
procmail: Notified comsat: "root@0:/dev/null"
From foo@bar  Thu Dec  1 06:57:20 2016
 Subject: [BULKMAIL] testing
  Folder: /dev/null                             133
```

If you still can't get this to work, updating your question with a similar transcript whould be most helpful.  Further troubleshooting tips can be found e.g. at http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Once you are satisfied that your code works, maybe you'll want to prefer `formail -I` over `formail -i` which leaves the now rather useless `Old-Subject:` in the headers.

(Your prose description says `BULK` but the code says `BULKMAIL`.  It is obviously easy to change if your code was wrong.)

The Webmin stuff is truly atrocious but apparently it's not your own code.  Somebody should supply the Webmin folks with a hint that Procmail contains a regex engine, so calling `/bin/test` to compare two strings is really, really inefficient and generally horrendous.

Comment: Very helpful. Also to inspect the final result `DEFAULT` can point to a temporary path and if non-existent just gets created as a .mbox